# socket.io giving issue with node.js / express.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express

I'm playing a bit with node.js and socket.io. This is the piece of code I'm writing:

```
app.get('/play', function (req, res) {
//some code you don't need to see
var gameMessage = io.of('/game'+gameId);
});
```

Everything is imported correctly. `gameId` is correctly set and the `io` variable is correctly initialized.
When running this code (when trying to access localhost/play) I get this error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/game/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:74:31)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

If I comment out the `var gameMessage` line of code, I don't get the error. So that's generating it.

I would like that line to stay there because it's instantiating a channel that I need. In this way two people can play together my game. If I don't instantiate that and try to run some code in the client side like

```
var chat = io.connect('http://localhost/chat' + gameId);
        chat.emit('guess', {
            guess: "ciao"
        });
        chat.on('guess', function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

I get an infinite loop of error in the console as the second player connects.

Can someone guess what's wrong with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong, you shouldn't put that Socket.IO code into your route, Express.js apps and Socket.IO apps don't "connect" like that.

Make a separate file with your Socket.IO server, then use [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) when you want to connect to Socket.IO (from the server side OR client-side) to send a message for example.

Comment: I would like to have a separate channel for each pair of players, but these channels will be created as the two players are connected. Is it possible doing something like this?

Comment: You can do something else, make every user connect to his channel. When "Alex" for example sends a message to "Jim", "Jim" will get the message because it listens to the "Jim" channel, and vice-versa.